# JsonAnyGetter / JsonAnySetter the resulting JSON has doubled values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to write a JSON string that follows this basic format:

```
"gesamtAngebot":{
    "angebotList":[{
        "instanzId":"string",
        "buchungsKontextList":[{
            "quellSystem":"SOMETHING",
            "payload":{}
        }],
        "payload":{"test1":"test1"}
    }]
}
```

I'm using the following class to present the data, and an instance of this class is serialized with the Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
@Data
public class Angebot {

    private String instanzId;

    private List<BuchungsKontext> buchungsKontextList;

    private Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> any() {
        return payload;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        payload.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

If I serialize an instance of this class as-is, the resulting JSON will be something like this:

```
"gesamtAngebot":{
    "angebotList":[{
        "instanzId":"string",
        "buchungsKontextList":[{
            "quellSystem":"SOMETHING",
            "payload":{}
        }],
        "payload":{"test1":"test1"},
        "test1":"test1"
    }]
}
```

As you can see the data of "payload" is doubled as it's own element and I don't have any idea why.

Thanks in advance for your attention and advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to serialize `payload` as a normal map. So if you don't want it there twice then you should not have the `any()` method, just have a regular getter method for `payload`.

The `any()` method can be used in case you want to serialize all the items from the `payload` map to appear like they are properties of `Angebot` class. Then you would use the `any` method, and not have a getter for `payload`.

Your JSON would come out like this:

```
"gesamtAngebot":{
    "angebotList":[{
        "instanzId":"string",
        "buchungsKontextList":[{
            "quellSystem":"SOMETHING",
            "payload":{}
        }],
        "test1":"test1"
    }]
}
```

And it will look like `test1` is a variable of the `Angebot` class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but actually I would like to use the "payload" as a anonym container for all the elements which I'm not interested in but which are in the JSON payload (test ist just one element, there could be more of them). That's why I'm using anygetter / -setter. It should look like in the first json file.

Comment: @Gremi you should just remove the `any()` method like I said, and you will have the correct JSON

Comment: Thanks @tima, this worked! Sometimes one should read the docu, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `any()` getter. Just remove it:

```
@Data
public class Angebot {

    private String instanzId;

    private List<BuchungsKontext> buchungsKontextList;

    private Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//    @JsonAnyGetter
//    public Map<String, Object> any() {
//        return payload;
//    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        payload.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

`payload` is class property. It gets naturally de-serialized because of `@Data` annotation. `any()` getter creates duplicity.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct you can mark it as accepted - it helps others when they find your question. It is also a good sign of you that you value others help. People will be more inclined to help you next time.  Also you and me will receive some reputation points.